# flutter: Get document from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to bring out the document id '1004' of the model collection. How can I do it?
I only know the Collection and Document id '1004'.

**Error code:**

```
DocumentSnapshot _model =  await carCollectionRef
          .doc()
          .collection(USER_CAR_COLLECTION)
          .doc()
          .collection(MODEL_COLLECTION)
          .doc('1004')
          .get();
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Error: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which
does not exist
The document id is the id copied from firebase. The same error occurred.

Comment: There is no way as i know you can get it without full path. The only thing you could do is restructure your database to get rid of deep nested collections.

Comment: @SimonSot are you sure ? `doc()` and `collection()` return a reference so it should be right to call them like this I suppose.

Comment: @Maxouille a document path must be a non-empty string, so you must pass path to doc().

Comment: "I only know the Collection and Document id '1004'." => Which collection do you know? MODEL_COLLECTION?

Comment: MODEL_COLLECTION ==> 'model', if you know the document ID from the model collection. Yes, if you read the QR code with the document ID, you want to show the document.

Comment: @SimonSot oh yes you're right, sorry ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure to understand your question but it seems that you would need to use a [Collection Group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#collection-group-query) on the `model` collections.

For that you will need to save the ID of each model document in a field within this document, in order to write a query along the following lines:

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('moodels').where('docId', isEqualTo: '1004').get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {...});
```

---

Note that you will get the models docs with ID == 1004 for **ALL** the `Cars` and `UserCars`. But without knowing the entire document path, there is no other way to find a doc in a sub-sub-collection with only its ID.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal way of getting data from `Firestore`. But this is how you can get it.

```
  foo() async {
   Map<String, dynamic> myData;

     await carCollectionRef
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
          if (element.exists) {
            carCollectionRef
                .doc(element.id)
                .collection('USER_CAR_COLLECTION')
                .get()
                .then((snapshot2) => snapshot2.docs.forEach((element2) {
                      if (element2.exists) {
                        carCollectionRef
                            .doc(element.id)
                            .collection('USER_CAR_COLLECTION')
                            .doc(element2.id)
                            .collection('MODEL_COLLECTION')
                            .doc('1004')
                            .get()
                            .then((value) => {
                                  if (value.exists) {myData = value.data()}
                                });
                      }
                    }));
          }
        }));

     print(myData);
  }
```